# Customize mongo-hacker prompt

Tags: mongodb, prompt

I want to customize the prompt in mongo-hacker on Mac. Too much space is being taken up with my (shortened) path, mongo version, and current db name.

```
My-Macbook(mongod13.2.4) myMongoDB >
```

My ideal prompt shows only the current database:

```
myMongoDB >
```

Comment: What have you tried? `function prompt () { return db + '> '; }` in your `~/.mongorc.js` should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can build the [mongo-hacker](https://tylerbrock.github.io/mongo-hacker/) from the source, following steps should solve your problem:

1. Clone the [mongo-hacker repo](https://github.com/TylerBrock/mongo-hacker) to your local computer.
2. Open hacks/prompt.js with your favorite text editor.
3. Change the return statement to  `return  db + '> ';`
4. Save and build.

Comment: Yep, that did it!  Back in the mongo-hacker directory, just ran 'make install' and re-ran 'mongo' in the project folder and it worked!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :)